# Order by number of records returned from child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to order like below:

```
@categories = Category.order(category.posts.count)
```

how can i make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerable.sort_by.

```
@categories = Category.all
@categories.sort_by { |category| category.posts.count }
```

The sad part is that you lose the lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
@categories = Category.select("COUNT(posts) as post_count").group("COUNT(posts)").order("post_count")
```